# IEquatable c#

Tags: c#

Господа, подскажите, почему код не компилится. Вроде, все правильно подставляю, а он ругается.

```
   interface IE<T>
{
    void Z();
}
class a <T> : IE<T>
{
    public void Z()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
    }
}
class b
{
    public static void F<T>() where T : IE<T>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        b.F<a<int>>();
    }
}
```

**Обновление**

> Ошибка    1   Не удается использовать тип
> "a<int>" в качестве параметра типа "V"
> для базового типа или метода
> "b.F<V>()". Отсутствует неявное
> преобразование ссылки из "a<int>" в
> "System.IEquatable<a<int>>".  C:\Users\Sergey\documents\visual
> studio
> 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs  25  9   ConsoleApplication2

Я не могу понять почему, ведь я же правильный аргумент типа подставляю.

Comment: И как ругается?

Comment:     public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj);
    }

Хм.

Comment: Но это вроде просто в райнтайме стек оверфлом, ругаться то не должен :-) Или шарп уже поумнел и на этапе компиляции такое отлавливает?

Comment: >The type 'a<int>' cannot be used as type parameter 'V' in the generic type or method 'b.F<V>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'a<int>' to 'System.IEquatable<a<int>>'

Читайте сообщение компилятора. Вроде все достаточно хорошо сформулировано. В чем проблема-то? 

З.Ы. у вас рекурсивный вызов метода **Equals**, на что вам намекает @VladD

Comment: Я не могу понять почему, ведь я же правильный аргумент типа подставляю

Comment: >ведь я же правильный аргумент типа подставляю

в том и прикол, что нет. очевидно же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите.

Ваше условие `where V : IEquatable<V>`. В вашем вызове `F<a<int>>()`, то есть `V = a<int>`, значит, необходимо `a<int> : IEquatable<a<int>>`. Но у вас есть лишь `a<int> : IEquatable<int>`.

---

Возможно, вы хотите на самом деле

```
public static void F<U, V>() where U : IEquatable<V>
```

и

```
b.F<a<int>, int>();
```

---

Стоп, наверное, правильно всё же вот как:

```
class a<T> : IEquatable<а<T>>
{
    ...
```

Вы ведь хотите, чтобы экземпляры `a<int>` можно было сравнивать с *другими* экземплярами `a<int>`, а не с `int`?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проясните, пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь:

1. Класс а есть обобщенный (шаблон), который подключает такой же обобщенный интерф.  
2. Когда я в параметр типа для класса "а" передаю аргумент, то, соответственно, этот аргумент так же принимает себе и интерф.   
3. Следовательно в этом вызове метода b.F<a<int>>(); я передаю вполне конкретный класс (уже не обобщ.), который реализует интерф. в соответствии с наложенными ограничениями. 

Где я ошибаюсь в своих суждениях, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: @polyakov_s: проблема в пункте 3: ваши ограничения прописаны так, что параметром интерфейса служит _сам класс_.

Comment: @polyakov_s: Обновил ответ, гляньте.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто почему такой код написал. Шилдт (аллах ему судья) пишет подключение интерефейса таким образом class a : IEquatable<a>. Но я захотел попробовать написать такой вариант class a<T> : IEquatable <T> для того, чтобы попробовать возможность на ходу сформировать тот тип данных, который обслуживает данный интерфейс. И вот поэтому в вызове метода я использую именно такую форму. А если в моей версии кода, то каким образом правильно вызвать этот метод?

Comment: Изменил код, чтобы убрать сбивающие с толку методы. Вот очень хочу понять, как правильно в этом случае вызвать этот метод?

Comment: @polyakov_s: В новом варианте тоже не получится: условие у вас `X : IE<X>`, а класс определён как `a<T> : IE<T>`, а не `a<T> : IE<a<T>>`.

Если вы хотите давать тип для `IE` отдельно, наверное вам надо задавать два типа: типа объекта и «обслуживающий» тип:

    public static void F<Z, T>() where Z : IE<T>

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное за терпение! Разобрался. 
Спасибо!!!

Comment: @polyakov_s: Пожалуйста!